# select xpath for div that doesn't have a child div with certain class name

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to select a parent div only when it doesn't have a child div with certain class name

I have tried this below xpath

`//div[@class = 'feH33N__mask'][//*[not(contains(@class, 'lifeImage'))]]`

but it selects all the parent with mask class[image: Here is the structure of DOM]

Comment: First, questions should provide a [mcve], posting images of code does not help. Second the predicate to point to a child is missing a dot `[.//*[not(contains(@class, 'lifeImage'))]]`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select a parent div only when it doesn't have a child div with certain class name

That would be

```
//div[not(child::div[contains(@class, 'lifeImage')]
```

Note:

- you can omit `child::` but I've included it for clarity.
- with //* you're searching the whole document, not just the children of the div in question.
- if you fix that, your code is looking for a div that has a child that isn't a lifeImage, which is not at all the same thing as looking for a div that doesn't have a child that is a lifeImage, which is what you said you wanted.